# Building Custom Type Hints

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.6, type-hinting

I have a simple class:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic

T = TypeVar('T')
class CustomParameter(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, value: T) -> None:
        print(value, T)
        self.value = value

    def get(self) -> T:
        print(self.value)
        return self.value
```

then I declare my custom type like this:

```
def is_dark(x: CustomParameter['Sunshine']) -> int: return x
```

How can I get the value `Sunshine` on from the type, so I can use it to check that the input is actually some object of type `Sunshine`?

Thanks

Comment: Could you give a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? As I understand it, you just want to do a runtime check `isinstance(x.value, Sunshine)`, right? It seems to me like you need to restructure your code so that `Sunshine` is a valid name to use.

Comment: @ethanhs I want to make a generic typing where a user can pass a string value.  So you can define a function like add(x:'int'=0), which is valid.  I was hoping I could make a generic['text'] typing, but I can't seem to access the text from the typing setting.

Comment: If you want to do this at runtime perhaps https://github.com/ilevkivskyi/typing_inspect is what you want?